# Есть ли случаи, когда в русском языке необходимы детерминативы? Если да, то какие это случаи?

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, грамматика, значение-слов, члены-предложения

> **Детерминати́в** – обязательный показатель при существительном,
> выражающий грамматическое значение определённости *(артикли, некоторые
> местоименные прилагательные) (в лингвистике)*.
>
> [Толковый словарь Т. Ф. Ефремовой]

> A **determiner** … is a word, phrase, or affix that occurs together
> with a noun or noun phrase and serves to express the reference of that
> noun or noun phrase in the context. That is, a determiner may indicate
> whether the noun is referring to a definite or indefinite element of a
> class, to a closer or more distant element, to an element belonging to
> a specified person or thing, to a particular number or quantity, etc.
>
> Детерминатив – это слово, сочетание слов или аффикс, которые используются
> вместе с существительным или именной группой и служат для выражения
> референции этого существительного или именной группы в контексте. То
> есть детерминатив может указывать, относится ли существительное к
> определенному или неопределенному объекту класса; к более близкому или
> более отдаленному объекту; к объекту, принадлежащему определенному
> человеку или предмету; к определенному числу или количеству и т. д.
> *(не дословный перевод с сохранением смысла)*
>
> [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner)]

---

Рассмотрим предложения:

*Писарь настолько потерялся, что **некоторое время** не мог выговорить ни одного слова.*
 Мамин-Сибиряк, Хлеб.

*Отчего она с **некоторых пор** стала сама не своя?*
Гончаров И. А., Обломов

*Бобров, все еще не пришедший в себя от удивления и в **некотором роде** негодования, не отвечал ему, так что друг Анжель обратился к доктору Звездичу, стоявшему с другой стороны.*
Гейнце Н. Э., Под гнётом страсти

*Стандартные опасения инфляции уступили место страху перед дефляцией, падающими ценами, что в **некоторых случаях** ещё опаснее для экономического роста.*
Ручир Шарма, Взлеты и падения государств. Силы перемен в посткризисном мире

---

Можно заметить, что в приведённых примерах нельзя обойтись без слова «некоторый», которое выполняет здесь функцию детерминатива — как сказано в словаре Ефремовой — обязательного показателя при существительном, выражающем грамматическое значение определённости.

---

Нельзя сказать:

*Писарь настолько потерялся, **что время** не мог выговорить ни одного слова.*

*Отчего она **с пор** стала сама не своя?*

*Бобров, все еще не пришедший в себя от удивления и **в роде** негодования, не отвечал ему, так что друг Анжель обратился к доктору Звездичу, стоявшему с другой стороны.*

*Стандартные опасения инфляции уступили место страху перед дефляцией, падающими ценами, что **в случаях** ещё опаснее для экономического роста.*

---

Слова: «время», «пор», «роде», «случаях» – в этих предложениях требуют детерминатива.

---

В английском языке детерминативы в большинстве случаев нужны. Их функции выполняют: артикли, местоимения и т. д.

Рассмотрим предложение:

*There’s **some milk** in the fridge.*
[пример c [english-at-home.com](https://www.english-at-home.com/grammar-there-some-any/)]

Не говорят:
***There’s milk** in the fridge.*

Существительное «milk» нуждается в детерминативе. Однако использовать тут артикль «a» выражающий референцию к неопределенному объекту класса, нельзя, поскольку молоко неисчисляемо. Как альтернатива используется детерминатив «some» — неопределённое количество того, что называется молоком.

*There’s **some milk** in the fridge.*
*В холодильнике есть **некоторое** количество молока.*

---

В приведённых мной примерах использование слова «некоторый» очень похоже на использование детерминатива «some» в английском языке.

*Писарь настолько потерялся, что **некоторое время** не мог выговорить ни одного слова.*

Если перевести:
*The scribe was so confused that for **some time** he could not utter a single word.*

---

Почему «время» требует «некоторое»? Почему нельзя сказать *«…что время…»*? Может это как-то связано с тем, что время неисчисляемо? Но «время» не всегда требует «некоторое».

Например:
*Таким образом, я имею **некоторое время** для того, чтобы вспомнить, прежде чем погибнуть, о своих открытиях.*
Иван Ефремов, Сердце змеи (сборник).

Тут «некоторое» можно убрать:
*Таким образом, я **имею время** для того, чтобы вспомнить, прежде чем погибнуть, о своих открытиях.*

В данном примере «некоторое» **имеет семантическое значение**:

> НЕ́КОТОРЫЙ, -ая, -ое, мест. неопределенное.
> …
> 2. Кое-какой, незначительный…
>
> [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

«Некоторое» можно заменить:
*Таким образом, я имею **кое-какое** время **[немного времени]** для того, чтобы вспомнить, прежде чем погибнуть, о своих открытиях.*

Однако в:
*Писарь настолько потерялся, что **некоторое время** не мог выговорить ни одного слова*
«некоторое» значит:

> НЕ́КОТОРЫЙ, -ая, -ое, мест. неопределенное.
>
> 1. Какой-то, точно не определенный.
>    …
>
> [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]

В данном случае слово «некоторое» фактически не имеет семантического значения, а выполняет функцию детерминатива, выражая неопределённость.

---

**Мои вопросы следующие:**

- Почему в приведённых примерах нельзя обойтись без слова «некоторый»? Какой
  закон тут работает?
- Есть ли случаи, когда в русском языке необходимы
  детерминативы? Если да, то какие это случаи?

Comment: Для всех приведенных примеров верна следующая закономерность. Если **некоторое время/количество/пора** нельзя заменить на **время/количество/пора**, то оно является обстоятельством и отвечает на вопросы типа когда, сколько, итп.
Если **некоторое время/пора/количество** можно заменить на **время/пора/количество**, то оно является дополнением/подлежащим и отвечает на вопросы типа что.

Comment: Артикли в английском не связаны с понятиями дополнение/обстоятельство. У нас же, судя по примерам - прямая связь. Отсюда вывод, что это разные оперы

Comment: @user190920 Насчёт того что в одних случаях обстоятельство в других дополнение, вы подметили, вреде бы, правильно. Но так ли это всегда? Я эти примеры выбрал случайно, может так просто совпало. Надо думать.

Comment: @user190920 Я подумал, возможно, потому что тут требуются ответы на вопросы обстоятельства, требующие конкретный ответ, например: *Как долго?* Можно ответить: «час», потому что «час» — это исчисляемое существительное: 1 час, 2 часа, 3 часа; но нельзя отвить «время», потому что оно неисчисляемое: 1 время, 2 времени, 3 времени — так не может быть; поэтому используется «некоторое», или например «мало/много времени», что была определённость.

Comment: @user190920 [Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2_(%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)): «Обычно к **детерминативам относят** артикли (определенные, неопределённые, частичные), демонстративы (указательные местоимения), поссесивы (притяжательные местоимения), **квантификаторы (слова для отражения количественных отношений, например, *много, некоторые*)**, числительные, вопросительные слова и дистрибутивы (определительные местоимения)».

Comment: @user190920 Спасибо за хорошую мысль, насчёт обстоятельств и дополнений.

Answer (score 1):

Детерминатив *некоторое* указывает на продолжительность того или иного эпизода, масштаб которого определяется контекстом (см. примеры с временными по нисходящей — от десятилетий до секунд). Необходимость в  детерминативе безусловна; по определению он является дополнительным элементом с вспомогательной функцией и способствует более точному прочтению основного слова.

> Если действительно является исторической необходимостью.., то
> большевистский режим,  если бы он продержался еще несколько времени,
> пришел бы, несмотря на всю свою идеологическую ненависть, к «праву
> собственности на орудия производства». [П. Н. Савицкий. Континент
> Евразия (1916-1968)]
>
> Лет 5 тому назад он приехал ко мне, посмотрел библиотеку для детей и
> через несколько времени прислал мне в подарок чудесную большую картину
> «Конек Горбунок», где в каждом мазке чувствуется его ясность души и
> его доброта. [К. И. Чуковский. Дневник (1963)]
>
> Проходит несколько времени ― и границы владений младенца раздвигаются.
> [Александр Архангельский. Александр I (2000)]
>
> Рассказчик возвращается к анатомической схеме и некоторое время стоит.
> [Евгений Гришковец. Одновременно (2004)]

Comment: *«Необходимость в детерминативе безусловна»*, но ведь в русском, в отличие от английского, детерминативы используются редко. Да и в английском языке, есть случаи, когда они не нужны. Например, в предложении с [lexico.com](https://www.lexico.com/): *“The trees grow fruit with appetizing flavor: blue apples, green oranges, and bananas” (На деревьях растут фрукты с аппетитным вкусом: голубые яблоки, зеленые апельсины и бананы)* – артикль есть только у деревьев, ни у фруктов, ни у вкуса, ни у яблок, апельсинов и бананов, артикля нет. (1/2)

Comment: Необходима определённость только в том, какие деревья мы имеем в виду. Именно на тех, определённых деревьях. Значит наличие детерминатива не безусловно, а подчиняется условиям. При одних условиях он нужен, при других нет. Так и в русском языке, в большинстве случаев не нужен, но есть условия при которых нужен. (2/2)

Comment: Почему в приведённых примерах нельзя обойтись без слова «некоторый»? Какой закон тут работает? === Ответ на этот вопрос я дал, попутно опровергая утверждение, что детерминатив выражает неопределённость. Вывод: когда выражается определённость размерности продолжительности эпизода, детерминатив необходим. Не о деревьях речь, — о времени.